# Import parent template with subchart values

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have multiple sucharts with applications and a parent chart that will deploy them.

All subcharts have the same manifests for the underlying application. Therefore I decided to create a library and put general variables from subcharts in it.

Example from lib:

```
{{- define "app.connect.common.release.common_libs.servicetemplate" -}}  
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
  name: {{ .Values.application.name }}-service
  namespace: {{ .Values.global.environment.namespace }}
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: {{ .Values.application.name }}
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
{{- end }}
```

I declared a dependency in Chart.yaml and executed `helm dep up`. Then in my subchart I'm importing this template. But when I'm trying to run --dry-run on parent chart I'm receiving the following error:

```
Error: template: app.connect.common.release/charts/app.connect.common.release.chtmgr/templates/service.yaml:1:4: executing "app.connect.common.release/charts/app.connect.common.release.chtmgr/templates/service.yaml" at <include "app.connect.common.release.common_libs.servicetemplate" .>: error calling include: template: app.connect.common.release/charts/app.connect.common.release.chtmgr/charts/app.connect.common.release.common_libs/templates/_helpers.tpl:169:18: executing "app.connect.common.release.common_libs.servicetemplate" at <.Values.application.name>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.name
```

My values values.yaml in the subchart:

```
application:
  name: chtmgr-api
  image: cht-mgr-api
```

The same error with named template.

**Is it possible to put general values from subchart in parent template(example _helper.tpl) and import it in subchart?**

If not, how do you implement this?

I've checked a lot of resources but still don't have an idea am I going in the right direction.

Comment: Push [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to github repo and provide a link to it. I dont really want to guess whats wrong and would rather see the complete (not)working example.

Comment: it's a private repo therefore can't share this(

Comment: Just create a new one with minimal example reproducing the issue

Comment: https://gitlab.com/spheal/examples/-/tree/master/helm/helm
To see the error just run: ```helm template --debug --dry-run ibext.connect.common.release```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Problem was related to the chart/template names all of them include '.' in the names what causes problem. **Don't include dots in your templates/charts names**. Example how not to do: "ibext.common.connect.etc".

**My assumption**

*I'm quite newbie in helm and my assumption that helm when template engine is looking in the subchart it goes through the following way to find variables .Values.subchartName in my case it was .Values.ibext.common.connect.etc So when it faced with .Values.ibext it can't understand what it is(but helm doesn't show anything)*.

**But this is only my assumption**. If someone there understands the behaviour of template engine in this case please reveal the secret.

Answer (score 1):

The Helm template `define` action creates a "function".  It implicitly takes a single "parameter", using the special variable name `.`, and `.Values` is actually a lookup in `.`.  It does not "capture" `.Values` at the point where it is defined; it uses the `Values` property of the parameter that's passed to it.

This means the template will behave differently when it's called in different contexts.  As the Helm documentation on [Subcharts and Global Variables](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/) describes, when executing the subchart, the top-level `.` parameter will have its `Values` replaced by the subchart's key in the primary values.

There's three ways to work around this:

1. If you're using Helm 3, you can [directly import a value](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#using-the-child-parent-format) from the subchart into the parent.  (I'm not clear what version of Helm exactly this was added, or if the syntax works in a separate `requirements.yaml` file.)  Declare the subchart dependency in your `Chart.yaml` as

   ```yaml
   dependencies:
      - name: subchart
        import-values:
          - child: application
            parent: application
   ```

   and the template you show should work unmodified.

   (There's a [more involved path](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#using-the-exports-format) that involves the subchart explicitly exporting values to the parent.  I'm not sure if this is that useful to you: the paths will still be different in the two charts, and in any case Helm values can't contain computed values.)
2. You already use `.Values.global` in your example; this will have the same value in the parent chart and all included charts.

   ```yaml
   #                vvvvvv  inserted "global" here
   name: {{ .Values.global.application.name }}-service
   namespace: {{ .Values.global.environment.namespace }}
   ```
3. You can also use template logic to try to look in more places for the `application` dictionary.  This will only work from the parent chart and the subchart proper and not any other sibling charts; I believe it will also only work if the configuration is embedded in the parent chart's `values.yaml` or an external `helm install -f` values file, but won't find content in the included chart's `values.yaml`.

   ```yaml
   {{/* Get the subchart configuration, or an empty dict (assuming we're in the parent) */}}
   {{- $subchart := .Values.subchart | default dict -}}
   {{/* Find the application values (assuming first we're in the subchart) */}}
   {{- $application := .Values.application | default $subchart.application | default dict -}}
   {{/* Then use it */}}
   name: {{ $application.name }}-service
   ```

   This logic sets the variable `$application`, normally, to `.Values.application`.  If that's not set (you're in the parent chart) then it in effect looks up `.Values.subchart.application`, and if that's not available either then it uses an empty dictionary.  This is (again, using programming terminology) eagerly evaluated – even if you're not falling back to the default, Helm will always look up `.Values.subchart` – so we use a second variable to have the `.Values.subchart`, or an empty dict (if you're in the subchart).  In both cases looking up a nonexistent key in an empty dict isn't an error but looking up on an unset value is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. There are some pitfalls. 1. I need a schema that will work with all sibling charts. 2. Global values is also not an option because I'll have the same variables for all charts. 3. I've tried to use a lib chart but getting the same error as in named charts. I'll check a bit later about import-values looks interesting I've haven't spotted it in docs before.

Comment: I tried to use import-values and faced with the following: 1. Warnign: dependencies.go:260: Warning: ImportValues missing table: "ibext" is not a table. 2. Still get the same error related to scope of the variable. It is possible that I did something incorrect. One note that currently I'm trying to fix the issue using lib chart.

Comment: #3 is brilliant, thank you so much for sharing 

Answer (score 0):

Be aware the *.tpl files must be in the **templates** folder. Double check all folder names and the structure.